# class to class type conversion through constructor method output is 5500 why not 5555

Tags: c++, class, initialization, construct, move-assignment-operator

Output is 5500, but why not 5555?

```
class product {
public:
    int b;
};

class item {
public:
    int a;
    item(product& obj)
    {
        cout << a;
    }
    item() {}
    void display()
    {
        cout << a;
    }
};

int main()
{
    item obj1;
    product obj2;
    obj1.a = 5;
    cout << obj1.a;
    obj1.display();
    obj1 = obj2;
    //object of product class sent into Constructor of item class*
    cout << obj1.a;
    return 0;
}
```

Here constructor is called of item class and product object is pass through it.

Comment: Can you explain why you think it should be 5555?

Comment: Note that when you do `product obj2;` `obj2.b` has an indeterminate value, so reading from it is undefined.

Comment: https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/ub - you broke the rules of the language, your program is meaningless.

Comment: @ScottHunter... first 2 five because of cout<<obj1.a and obj1.display();....than next five is as i call obj1 constructor passing obj2 in it than the constructor is of obj1.. body contain cout<<a so it print the value of a of obj1... and then again 4th five due to cout<<obj1.a in main function

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The program has undefined behavior because the used data member `a` is not initialized.

This conversion constructor

```
        item(product &obj)
        {
           cout<<a;
        }
```

that is used in this assignment statement

```
obj1=obj2;
```

to convert the object `obj2` of the type `product` to an object of the type `item` does not initialize the data member `a`. So the data member has an indeterminate value. And this indeterminate value assigned to the data member `a` of the object `obj1` is outputted in the constructor and in this statement

```
cout<<obj1.a;
```

It occurred such a way that the memory occupied by the data member `a` of the temporary object of the type `item` contained zeroes. But in general this is not necessary.

Comment: Sir i initialize a in main function for obj1 ..third line after int main obj1.a=5 ??

Comment: @Karmeshjain Yes, you did. But then you overwrote  obj1 with obj2 that has uninitialized data member a.